# Sending Telnet commands on Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, telnet

I am trying to send some commands over telnet.
Everything works fine when executed locally on a PC on basis of a swing GUI, but when using the same code on Android, the app freezes for a few seconds and the commands are not carried out (same result on emulator and real device), although it runs to the end. No error message is being thrown, but after this procedure the device is not reachable via Telnet, not even via PC (restart of target device is then necessary). What I do not understand is that it seems that the 500 milliseconds restriction I set is being ignored on Android.

I am a novice on Android so please bear with me. Glad for any help.

```
package com.test.test.remote;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void calculate(View view) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Calc button executed");
        command("MO");
    }

    public String command(String cmd) {
        String output = "test";

        Log.e("Msg", "command reached");
        Log.e("Msg", cmd);

        Socket pingSocket = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;

        pingSocket = new Socket();
        try {
            pingSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("10.10.10.107", 23), 500);
            out = new PrintWriter(pingSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    pingSocket.getInputStream()));
            out.println(cmd);
            output = in.readLine();
            out.close();
            in.close();
            pingSocket.close();
            System.out.println(output);
            Log.e("Msg", "end of command reached");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("com.example.test.MainActivity", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

XML:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp" >

    <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/kmh" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:onClick="calculate"
            android:text="@string/calc" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.test.remote"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Why are you calling `readLine()` twice?

Comment: Agreed. `System.out.println(in.readLine()); output = in.readLine();` should be `output = in.readLine(); System.out.println(output);` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your input. You are correct, unfortunately it does not fix the issue.

Comment: Did you found any solution ?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.